# Impossible to add new font / react-native-asset

Tags: reactjs, node.js, react-native, fonts

I'm trying to add new fonts to my react native project but it's not working.

I created an `assets/fonts` folder and put fonts in it. I also created an `react-native.config.js` file, at the root of the project and put this code inside it:

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
        ios: {},
        android: {}
    },
    assets: ['./assets/fonts'],
};
```

(I'm sure it's the right path)

I've installed the react-native-asset library globally, and when I run the `npx react-native-asset` command to link the font, I get this error:

```
node:internal/validators:162
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE(name, 'string', value);
    ^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "paths[1]" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at validateString (node:internal/validators:162:11)
    at Object.resolve (node:path:167:9)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\aymer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-asset\lib\get-config.js:13:12)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\aymer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-asset\lib\index.js:188:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aymer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\react-native-asset\lib\cli.js:56:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12) {
  code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}

Node.js v18.17.1
```

How can I resolve this error or install fonts differently please?

Thanks for any help !

My native react version is 0.71.14

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there might be an issue with the version compatibility of the react-native-asset.

first of all Remove `react-native-asset` globally.

```
npm uninstall -g react-native-asset
```

```
npm install react-native-asset --save-dev
```

```
npx react-native-asset
```

if above are not work for you!?

You can try to Manually link the fonts

- Android -> android/app/src/main/assets/fonts
- iOS -> ios/{YourProjectName}/Fonts

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately uninstalling then reinstalling didn't change anything and my two folders android and ios, located at the root of the project, are empty, I really don't know where the problem comes from